# How to auto-format javascript to align multiple lines with require() statements

Tags: javascript, emacs, code-formatting, js-beautify

I am using js-beautify from [einars](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify), and I am trying to
configure the options to achieve the following format:

```
var a                   = require("lib-a"),
    alongvariable       = require("another-lib-a");
```

or

```
var a                   = require("lib-a");
var alongvariable       = require("another-lib-a");
```

Does a combination of option would allow to produce this layout ?

Comment: I'd suggest this https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular

Comment: Thanks, I must of mentionned, I am using gnu emacs.